# What is the best practice for images on websites?

Tags: image, html5, image-format

I am using right now svg images, because it looks great at any size, but not all the browsers has support for this. So, is it better practice work with .png/.jpg?

Comment: Is this a technical implementation question? Or are you concerned with the usability of image types?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical requirements on images. Possibly better asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this [site as a reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg). Pretty much all current browsers allow SVG, and even the versions before it too (pretty much).

For me, when it comes down to graphics, I use SVG because I create responsive sites, meaning I want my site to work on all devices, and SVG allows me to do that without having to create multiple versions of one image.

I suggest you use SVG it you're using icons that you want to be responsive along with your site, but stick to traditional PNGs if you want to create a static site.

However, I think eventually we'll all transition into SVGs because the future is pointing towards that way. Just like how it was GIFs before, now PNGs, and finally up coming are SVGs.

Answer (score 2):

As Wikipedia correctly points out, [JPEG is designed for digital photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), while PNG is a format better suited for non-photograpic images, like diagrams, icons, clipparts, etc... as JPEG [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) does a really poor job with these kind of images.

Using SVG is not even an option for digital photography. And it's a bad idea (for the reason you pointed out) in comparison with PNG for non-photographic images.

**EDIT**
And here is a short and good [answer to "What web graphics formats to use?"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/81/29801).